# Place Swipe Gesture over UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm wanting to be able to swipe right when using the video camera to hide the camera controls. The view presents just fine but when I swipe I get an error.

I'm getting the following error:

> VideoStream[13065:60b] -[UILayoutContainerView
>   toggleControlsWithGesture]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x1701a1960 2014-04-26 11:37:28.639 VideoStream[13065:60b] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILayoutContainerView
>   toggleControlsWithGesture]:

Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)startCameraControllerFromViewController:(UIViewController *)controller usingDelegate:(id)delegate
{
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil)) {
        return NO;
    }

    _cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    _cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    _cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    _cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;
    _cameraUI.delegate = delegate;

    [controller presentViewController:_cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                            initWithTarget:_cameraUI.view 
                                                    action:@selector(toggleControlsWithGesture)];
    swipeRight.delegate = self;

    //And assuming the "Up" direction in your screenshot is no accident
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [_cameraUI.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

    return YES;
}
```

This is the swipe code:

```
- (void)toggleControlsWithGesture
{
    NSLog(@"BOOM");
    if (_showsControls == YES) {
        _cameraUI.showsCameraControls = NO;
    } else {
        _cameraUI.showsCameraControls = YES;
    }
}
```

Any help that can be offered is GREAT appreciated.

Comment: `...-initWithTarget:_cameraUI.view ...` should be `initWithTarget:self` i.e. `UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleControlsWithGesture)];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:_cameraUI.view 
                                                action:@selector(toggleControlsWithGesture)];
```

do:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self
                                                action:@selector(toggleControlsWithGesture)];
```

---

### Explanation:

For your `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` object, you are currently doing `-initWithTarget:_cameraUI.view`.

This means the target that will respond to the specified action method will be `_cameraUI.view` **but** `_cameraUI.view` does not provide any `-toggleControlsWithGesture` method and hence the error.
The `-toggleControlsWithGesture` method will be found in this class and so you will need to specify the target as `self`.

---

**Example:** Consider in **XYZClass.m**, we do something like:

```
ABCClass *abcObject = [ABCClass alloc] init];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:abcObject 
                                       action:@selector(doSomething)];
```

This basically says that the `abcObject` will respond to the event by firing a `doSomething` method.
**But**... for this to happen, `ABCClass` should have defined the `doSomething` method.

In your case, `_cameraUI` is of `UIImagePickerController` class and it's `view` may be a property or another class object. In either case, it does not have the `-toggleControlsWithGesture` method which ***you*** created for your purposes.